# Count number of shared_ptr in existence

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a data class where I usually pass objects of this class around using shared_ptr. Now I'd like to try keep track of how many shared_ptr's exist to objects of that class. Note that this is not the same as how many pointers there are to a specific object. Primarily I want this to help identify possible memory leaks but also there are situations where knowing the actual number is useful.

One idea I had was to keep a static list of weak pointers to every shared_ptr constructed. I could then periodically check to see how many of the weak pointers are still valid. The problem here is, how do I automatically add a weak pointer to the list every time a shared_ptr is created? Will a custom allocator work?

Does anyone know of a reasonable way to do this?

Comment: I'm curious what useful situations you can think of for needing this information.  IMHO, the performance cost of implementing this far exceeds any benefit.  Memory leaks should be debugged using your platform's debugging facilities, and the overall number of objects isn't very useful because you don't know anything about how they are used.  Are they all in one container?  If so, just use `container.size()`.  Otherwise, how do you know how many objects are used by each container/data structure etc?  How many of the objects correspond to local variables, temporaries, etc?

Comment: Performance costs are very relative and try to be less judgmental unless you know the application. Right now, the most important thing for me is to confirm that my algorithms are doing what I expect them to do. It is sometimes nice to know if I have roughly 1000 objects in memory versus 100,000. Also, for memory leak detection the performance hit for counting objects is less than using something like valgrind (which is non-trivial to get setup for android).

Comment: No judement was intended; I was legitimately curious.  The opinions I expressed come from developing primarily for desktop ecosystems.  Your point about the difficulties of debugging mobile apps is not something I had thought of, so thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a wrapper or factory where you get all your `shared_ptr`, so that at the same time, you can do your side accounting.

```
template<class T, class... Args>
  typename std::shared_ptr<T> make_recorded(Args... ar)
  { 
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr= make_shared<T>(ar) ;
    // add your annotation/tracking here
    return ptr ;
  }
```

Comment: Will likely need to specify a custom deleter in `make_recorded` to ensure cleanup of the annotations if necessary.